# What are some popular Git layout strategies?

Tags: git, layout, blogs, structure

A fellow developer recently showed me a blog post with a nice visual representation of a git layout.  He implied that this particular strategy was gaining a lot of popularity, but numerous searches here and through the Google have yet to turn up the blog post.

The gist of it was that you had a trunk for main development, and a "side-trunk" for immediate customer-driven bug fixes.  Main development had a branch, which was merged to trunk periodically for major releases, and then you had feature branches. There was a lovely diagram that clearly showed all this.

Since I'd like to learn git better, I'd love to have that diagram available as an aide.  It'd also be useful as a visual for trying to convince coworkers to switch to git.  Does anyone happen to know what I'm talking about and can provide a link?

EDIT:
I realize now that my title is a bit misleading to the content.  If anyone would like to post additional strategies for git branching, they would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about [this workflow titled "A Successful git branching model"](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).  The folks at nvie also created the [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) subcommand that implements the branching model described in the first link.  A blog post about the git-flow tool can be found [here](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/).   Do note, however, that git-flow can be a bit tricky to set up on Windows.  On *IX machines, it's very straight forward.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you very much, and thanks extra for the warning about Windows.  As I primarily work on Windows, I'll be on the look out for snagging points.